# Examples of $C^{k,1}$ functions which are not $C^{k+1}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, examples, counterexamples

I'm currently reading [this paper](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v161-n1-p10.pdf) and the authors define the set $C^{k,1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as consisting of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ having $k$ derivatives and for which:
$$
\|f\|:= \max_{|\beta|<k}\left[ \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |(D^{\beta}f)(x)|
+
\sup_{x,y;\, x\neq y} \frac{|(D^{\beta}f)(x)-(D^{\beta}f)(y)|}{\|x-y\|}
\right]<\infty.
$$

However, I'm having trouble understanding non-trivial examples of such functions (e.x.: if $f$ is a polynomial of degree $k-1$.)

So I ask: *What are examples of functions* in $C^{k,1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but not in $C^{k+1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?*

Specifically, I imagine there is some condition to show that "piecewise polynomial functions of degree at-most $k$" belong to $C^{k,1}$.?

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if you cited the paper you are reading.

Comment: @EFinat-S I added the paper link.

Comment: When $k$ is even: $\frac{1}{1 + |x|^{k+1}}$.

Comment: Shouldn't that read $|\beta| \le k$ below the maximum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n=1$ and $k=1$, let
$$f(x)=x^2 \sin(1/x)$$
for real $x\ne0$, with $f(0)=0$. Then $f\in C^{k,1}(\mathbb R^n)\setminus C^{k+1}(\mathbb R^n)$.

It should be easy to extend this example to the other $n$ and $k$.

Comment: Thanks, Im wondering if this set contains some sort of "higher-order" splines...